# python redirect standard stream of subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to do online coding platform using python as backend. I'm using `subprocess.Popen`
to run user's code. Now I want to interact with it. One way I know is using `pipe` and `dup2`
but problem with it is it changes standard i/o in context of my whole backend application.
I want std streams change with respect to subprocess only.

Any args that I can pass to `subprocess.Popen` so that main python app can access std stream of its subprocess?

Example:

```
import subprocess
args=['py',path+'t.py']
p = subprocess.Popen(args)
```

t.py is Hello World program. subprocess will print Hello World in terminal but I want it to redirect to other file descriptor so that I can access in an variable and send it over network. Same goes with input.

**UPDATE:**

I did

```
r,w=os.pipe()

p = subprocess.Popen(args,stdout=w)
```

for this I get error

```
 Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Comment: could you show your code yet and what you've tried  please ?

Comment: @R.LM I hope now its clear what I want to do.

Comment: and what you want is basically the output of the program ran right ?

Comment: @R.LM also control over input.What I'm expecting is if I write something to certain fd it should be input to that subprocess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subprocess Popen` provides additional named parameters for this type of things with `PIPE` as you mentionned

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

args=['py',path+'t.py']

# errors included
p = Popen(args, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)

#BufferedWriter for input
input_stream = p.stdin

#BufferedReader for output
output_stream = p.stdout


print(output_stream.read())
```